# Can anyone identify what the name of this outfit this is?

Tags: runescape

[image]

I've searched through all of the outfits available from Solomon's General Store via the wikia, but I have had no luck. It may be pieces of more than one outfit, but they seem too similar to not be a part of a complete outfit. More specifically, I'm trying to find what the hat/top/bottoms are, and the gloves as well if possible.

Comment: Where did you get this picture from?

Comment: @murgatroid99 I figured the tag worked well enough for identifying the game, but if you don't recognize it then it's unlikely you'd be able to find the answer (I don't mean this in any offensive way, but I'd imagine it would fairly difficult to research an image for a game if you haven't played it :P).

Comment: I don't mean the game. I know the game. I was wondering if you got the image from a website, or you took it yourself. (I don't mean this in any condescending way, but the source of an image might help identify its content).

Comment: Oh, it's a screenshot. Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hat is from the [Cabaret Outfit](http://runescape.wiki/w/Cabaret_Outfit).

[image]

The top and bottom are from the [Samba outfit](http://runescape.wiki/w/Samba_outfit).

[image]

The cape is the [Clan Cloak](http://runescape.wiki/w/Clan_cloak)

[image]

The gloves are [Static Gloves](http://runescape.wiki/w/Static_gloves).

[image]

That is a [Zaryte Bow](http://runescape.wiki/w/Zaryte).

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to know what cape that is, as well? I didn't realize the piece around her neck wasn't part of the top, so I can only assume it's the cape. Didn't get much of a screenshot of that though, so if you can't that's perfectly fine, and thanks for finding all of the other pieces as well.

Comment: Hmmm I was confused by that as well.  Initially I thought it might be untrimmed Slayer cape but it does not match.  So I am still looking but it has me stumped...Sorry.  Not giving up though! :)

Comment: @RXC I'm probably wrong, but it could be a clan cape. They might be stars on the bottom of the cape, which a clan cape gets when you work in the citadel.

Comment: Thanks @Haidro!  Of course I didn't think of looking for "Cloak" since it is called a Clan Cloak.  I was just looking for cape.  I can't seem to find a view on the wikia of the front view but from in game view I think it is the clan cloak.  I will update my answer and later I will update with a in game screenshot from the front if I get a chance.